# limit of $\frac{x^3+4x^2+2y^2}{2x^2+y^2}$ as $(x,y)\to (0,0)$

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

Find the following limit if it exists; otherwise, explain why the limit does not exist.
(i) Limit of $(x^3+4x^2+2y^2)/(2x^2+y^2)$ when $(x,y)$ tends to $(0,0)$.

I know the limit is $2$ but I don't know how to prove it using sandwich theorem that it exists. Don't know how to continue as I got to $|x^3/(2x^2+y^2)|$... please assist.

Answer (score 2):

Then use that
$$
|x^3|\le|x|·(x^2+\tfrac12y^2)
$$

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can use polar coordinates to show the limit:

$$x = r \cos \theta$$
$$y = r \sin \theta$$

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{x^3+4x^2+2y^2}{2x^2+y^2} = \lim_{r\to 0}\frac{r^3 \cos^3\theta+4r^2 \cos^2 \theta+2r^2 \sin^2 \theta}{2r^2 \cos^2\theta+r^2 \sin^2 \theta} = \lim_{r\to 0}\frac{r \cos^3\theta+4 \cos^2 \theta+2\sin^2 \theta}{2 \cos^2\theta+ \sin^2 \theta} = \frac{4 \cos^2 \theta+2\sin^2 \theta}{2 \cos^2\theta+ \sin^2 \theta} = \frac{2(2 \cos^2 \theta+\sin^2 \theta)}{2 \cos^2\theta+ \sin^2 \theta} = 2 $$

Answer (score 2):

Another variation:

$$\frac{x^3+4x^2+2y^2}{2x^2+y^2}=\frac{x^3}{2x^2+y^2}+2\;,\;\;\text{since}\; (x,y)\neq (0,0)$$

and then, since clearly $\;2x^2+y^2\ge 2x^2\;$:

$$\left|\frac{x^3}{2x^2+y^2}\right|\le\frac{|x^3|}{2x^2}=\frac12|x|\xrightarrow[(x,y)\to(0,0)]{}0$$

Comment: i am a little confused.. if thats the case, isn't the limit 0?

Comment: @supman Read with greater care: the limit is $\;2\;$ , as written.

Comment: thanks i think i know whats my problem already!